# Problem with ifelse statement in rmarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an rmarkdown file Im knitting to pdf. I have an ifelse statement within a text chunk in the rmd file. It goes as following:

"In your x, the median score for x skills in the first assessment is `r params$median`. This means that the scores of the median child in your municipality are `r if (params$median > 50) "higher" else "lower"` than the national median.

Similarly, the 10th percentile represents the score that divides your x's children in such a way that 10% of the lowest scores are below it, and 90% are above it. In the first assessment of x skills, your x's 10th percentile is  `r params$prencetile`. This means that the lowest 10% of children in your x received scores that are `r if (params$precentile > 10) "higher" else "lower"` than the national 10th percentile."

The probelm is the second conditional statement: `r if (params$precentile > 10) "higher" else "lower"`. It correctly prints the parameter `r params$precentile`, but when the value is strictly under 10 it still prints "higher". The conditional statement works correclty for the median part. I dont know what the problem is and I have tried everything. Is there something Im missing? The statements are correctly formatted.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  In this case, we need to see a small Rmd file that reproduces the problem along with the code you (presumably) call to create the `params` object and render the Rmd.  Both "minimal" and "reproducible" are important attributes of the example.